# Manual Calculation for bs() Matrix in R

Tags: r, splines

I am new in R and learning on constructing spline. I came across for bs() function in R and I understand that it creates matrix for b-spline matrix. I, however, still don't understand how the function can get into the result.

For example, I have my code:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
a1 <- bs(x, knots = c(3))
print(a1)

           1    2       3     4
[1,] 0.00000 0.00 0.00000 0.000
[2,] 0.59375 0.25 0.03125 0.000
[3,] 0.25000 0.50 0.25000 0.000
[4,] 0.03125 0.25 0.59375 0.125
[5,] 0.00000 0.00 0.00000 1.000
attr(,"degree")
[1] 3
attr(,"knots")
[1] 3
attr(,"Boundary.knots")
[1] 1 5
attr(,"intercept")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"class")
[1] "bs"     "basis"  "matrix"
```

I understand that in this code I ask R to produce a matrix for cubic spline for data x and within the data I place knot at point 3. But I still don't get how R can generate the above matrix. I have checked online sources (including R documentation), however I have not got the result. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  Do you understand what B-splines are, and just don't see where the values in `a1` came from, or are you asking for an explanation of B-splines?  The former is more of a StackOverflow question.

Comment: I understand what b spline is, but I want to know how can I manually calculate (pencil and paper) for the matrix in a1 output. Thanks.

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34eVv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34eVv.png)I know this is really old, but I created a [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E8ozpvn5O1euQtNcaiMLqa-QP4Q_PBpoAX7TgeKYCkU/edit) that uses matrices to replicate and explain what is going on "under the hood" for B-spline implementation. I've been working on this problem a bunch and thought it would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `a1` matrix contains evaluations of 4 of the B-spline basis functions at the values in `x`.  There isn't a simple formula for those functions; Wikipedia gives
some non-simple ones.  A useful exercise is to include a finer grid of `x` values, and then to plot the 4 columns of `a1`:

```
x <- seq(1,5, len=100)
a1 <- bs(x, knots = 3)
matplot(x, a1)
```

[image: screenshot]

Since your knot is in the middle of the range, the basis functions should be symmetrically arranged around it; R leaves off function "0", which would be a mirror image of function 4, because it assumes you'll also use an intercept term as the fifth basis function.  If you had used `bs(x, knots = 3, intercept = TRUE)` it will include the full set of 5 basis functions in the matrix, and they will add up to the intercept term `f(x) = 1`.